# bind callback to directive without isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When binding a callback function to a directive it is important for me to execute this function with the right context. Now, as long as the directive has an isolated scope it is not a problem

```
<bar-foo callback="mycontroller.callback()"></bar-foo>
```

and the directive:

```
 ...
 scope:{
     callback: '&'
 },
 ...
```

Without an isolated scope I extract the callback from the $attrs attrubute

```
$scope.callback = $parse($attrs.callback)($scope);
```

But, now I cannot do

```
 <bar-foo callback="mycontroller.callback()"></bar-foo>
```

Because it will execute the callback directly. What would be the preferred way to solve this ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvzgpn5j/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a function in your controller which explicitly sets the value of `this` inside of this function:

```
this.exportableCallback = this.callback.bind(this);
```

where `this.callback` is the one you use for the isolated scope.

Second step is setting it as an attribute

```
<hello-world callback="mycontroller.exportableCallback"></hello-world>
```

where you **do not** call the function like you did with isolated scope.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvzgpn5j/5/).

Another option (if you remove `this.callback` from your controller) is

```
this.exportableCallback = function() {
  console.log(this.test);
}.bind(this);
```

If you want to pass arguments to this function:

```
this.exportableCallback = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: I did see this answer coming :) but I was hoping for something similar as in the case of an isolated scope. Thnx!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri isolated scopes do the similar thing :) They just hide it from our eyes

Answer (score 0):

As this scope isn't isolated isn't just a case of calling what you want?

```
    .directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="mycontroller.callback()">Not isolated</button>',
    }
});
```

and then just calling your directive?

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

Or am I missing something here?? Specifying the controller with the require attribute is also desirable.

Comment: what if you want to reuse the directive?

Comment: You would have to make sure the controller is available with the require, but I wouldn't really recommend this way of doing things. This was an example to answer the example. In my mind it's better to have it's own controller and call things in the isolated fashion, then that's reusable.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive without a scope, just access `mycontroller.callback()` in the directive template.

```
.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        //Use THIS
        template: '<button ng-click="mycontroller.callback()">Not isolated</button>',
        //NOT this                  
        //template: '<button ng-click="callback()">Not isolated</button>',
        controller: function ($attrs, $scope, $parse) {
              //$scope.callback = $parse($attrs.callback)($scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Since the directice has no scope of its own, the template has direct access to the controller which was instantiated with `ng-controller="MyCtrl as mycontroller"`.

---

> what if you want to reuse the directive?

In that case, bind a click handler to the element.

```
.directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        template: '<button>Not isolated</button>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
             elem.on("click", function(e) {
                 scope.$eval(attrs.callback, {$event: e});
             });
        }
    }
});
```

When the directive's element is clicked the Angular expression defined by the `callback` attribute will be evaluated with the event object exposed as `$event`.

For more information on `$event`, see [AngularJS Developer Guide -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-).

Comment: what if you want to reuse the directive?